# "Invalid Adapter: undefined" error in Edge Private mode while using PouchDB

Tags: microsoft-edge, pouchdb, web-sql, pouchdb-adapter-localstorage

While checking for pouchDB webSQL adapter

```
if (PouchDB.adapters.websql) {
    // code
}
```

I get "invalid adapter: undefined" error. Above code is working fine in all browsers except Edge (private mode). i checked the latest version of edge issue also exist on that version as well.

Doesn't edge support webSQL in private mode or is there any other thing which is wrong?

Comment: It looks like this issue is there in multiple browsers. I found that using in-memory adapter can be the work around for this issue. I suggest you to post your issue on PouchDB githib page. Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9968399/ and https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/5641

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you please guide me how can i use in-memory adapter in case of pouchDB...and yes i posted it as issue on pouchDB guthub page but they have not responded yet.

Comment: You can refer this documentation will be helpful to you. Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-adapter-memory